# Make an AtomicXXX object volatile

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I have read some info about volatile variables and their AtomicXXX counterparts, (e.g. AtomicBoolean).

But are there situations where I need to make the AtomicXXX object itself volatile, or is it never necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to - in fact, the atomic objects should really be set as `final`!!

Example:

```
private final AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0);

private volatile int volatileInt = 0;

public void doStuff() {
  // To use the atomic int, you use the setters and getters!
  int gotAnInt = atomicInt.getAndIncrement();

  // To use a volatile, access and set it directly. 
  int gotAnotherInt = volatileInt;
  volatileInt = someOtherInt;
}
```

Comment: Doesn´t the second assignment of volatileInt (volatileInt = someOtherInt;) include a read and a write and thus make the operation not atomic?

Comment: Yep, that is true. Apologies for implying otherwise - I'll remove the reference to atomicity! (FYI the assignment itself is atomic, but the read then write is not atomic)

Comment: So I should synchronize the doStuff() method to make it all atomic?

To the topic: So if the AtomicXXX is not declared as final, I should theoretically declare it as volatile if it is shared between different threads?

Comment: Nope - the internals of the AtomicInteger class handle the synchronisation for you. You don't need to make it volatile (and in fact, a final volatile variable makes no sense!)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml) for some tips and explanation when to use volatile. But basically if you are using AtomicXXX you DO NOT NEED to use volatile.